# app loses state when going to background when using sizeClassic in SwiftUI

Tags: swiftui, sidebar, size-classes, swiftui-tabview

I have a view created for the iPad with a Sidebar and another for the iPhone with a tabview. The problem is that when I use sizeClass, the SideBarView() view loses its state every time the app enters the background.

This does not happen if I use the SideBarView() view without the sizeClass conditional. Without that variable, it works correctly without any problem.

```
var body: some View {
    #if os(iOS)
    if horizontalSizeClass == .compact {
        TabMainView()
    } else {
        SideBarView()
    }
    #else //MacOSView
        SideBarView()
    #endif
}
```

Any idea?

Comment: The size class is likely changing when it goes to the background, which means your `SideBarView` is removed from the hierarchy. You haven't provided any code that relates to the state, so it's hard to say what's included, but you could consider persisting state somehow (scene storage, user defaults, etc)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have changed sizeClass to UIDevice to detect the device and show the corresponding view based on that. This has made the SideBar view work correctly without losing the state at any time.

Full code:

```
extension UIDevice {
static var idiom: UIUserInterfaceIdiom {
    UIDevice.current.userInterfaceIdiom
  }

static var isIpad: Bool {
    idiom == .pad
  }

  static var isiPhone: Bool {
    idiom == .phone
  }
 }


if UIDevice.isiPhone {
   TabMainView()
} else {
   SideBarView()
}
```

Comment: This is not a good solution, and iPad window can have different sizes. Instead you should extract the state from your view, or store it in scene storage.